# macOS machine seems to print a file, but then nothing comes out of the printer

Tags: networking, mac, printer

I've tried everything and the help desk at work isn't answering me, so I figured I would take a chance and ask you guys.

I am simply trying to print a text file. My Mac gives me a choice of a few network printers, showing status etc. No matter what printer I try to print with, my Mac goes through the motions of apparently sending data to the printer, gives no error message of any kind, says all is good… And then nothing ever comes out of the printer.

Anybody have a solution that I might be able to work while I'm waiting for a response from the help desk?

Comment: Does the printer receive data? Most printers have a flashing light when there is activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're comfortable with doing, you can try some of these methods, with the end being a total reset of the printers setup on your Mac.

- Check the printer for ink/toner and paper. (if you check within Settings -> Printers & Scanners and you can't access the toner levels, it's probably that your printer and Mac aren't connected via the network).
- If you're connected to the network via Wi-Fi, ensure you're connected to the right network.
- Use Software Update or App Store (under the Apple menu) or visit the printer manufacturer's website to see if there are any newer versions of your printer's software or drivers available.
- Cycle your printer off and on.
- If it's a USB printer, disconnect it and then reconnect it.
- Delete and reinstall the printer in the Printers & Scanners preference pane.

Finally, if none of those work, you can [Reset the Printing System](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18614). Then follow the link to [add any printers](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18606) back.